# Pentaho Report server - direct report access

Tags: redirect, authentication, response.redirect

I am accessing a reporting server named Pentaho. When I submit a report URL from my html page the server asks me to login on console. My user does not know the login, user want to see the report in first click. How to skip the login part.

Answer (score 1):

just put &userid=joe&password=password in the url.  Or whatever username/pass u have.